# Android AVD screen display big in xamarin how to change display setting

Tags: android, xamarin, android-virtual-device, display

Android AVD screen display big in xamarin how to change display setting
[image: AVD screen running time]

please help me to create AVD display (vs 2015 xamarin/c#) like display avd in android studio/java very clear and nice

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Visual Studio Emulators for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx). They are faster than avd and easy to use without having to set up anything.

Comment: i 've tried but not installed Visual Studio Emulator for Android....error setup block.. require 64 bit windows 8.1 and hyper V..   i've system amd processor 64 bit windows 10 , 8 gb ram.... amd processor not support....